# Como redireccionar un wordpress con php (o .htaccess) según idioma del usuario

Tags: php, wordpress, redirección, idioma

Necesito traducir un sitio web basado en Wordpress a diferentes lenguajes de manera automática.

He encontrado un plugin (Translatepress) cuya versión gratuita me permite traducir el sitio, por ejemplo, al inglés, y crea una url para ese idioma. Ejemplo:

http://localhost/silversea/   *//Url pordefecto*

http://localhost/silversea/en *//Url de la versión en inglés*

He probado cosas como esta:

```
    function custom_lang_found(){
    $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
    if( $lang == "en" ){
        $url = get_home_url()."/en/";
        wp_redirect( $url );
    }
}
```

Pero nada da resultado.

Objetivo, en resumen:  Redirigir a /en si la configuración de idioma del usuario es inglés.

Alguien puede orientarme un poco? No soy ni fan ni experto en PHP. Mas bien bastante novato y negado.

Gracias, comunidad!

PD: Pagaría felizmente una versión premium del plugin para aportar a los desarrolladores... pero no tengo esa posibilidad económica.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba este codigo, Me comentas si te funciono ;)

```
<?php 
//Creamos una función que detecte el idioma del navegador del cliente. 
function traeLenguage() { 
$idioma =substr($_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"],0,2); 
return $idioma; 
}
//Llamamos a la función y guardamos el idioma en una variable 
$idiomaUsuario = traeLenguage(); 
 
//De acuerdo al idioma hacemos las redirecciones según el lenguaje del navegador
if($idiomaUsuario=='es'){
header( 'Location: http://es.apartamentosembrujodeazahar.es' ); 
} 
elseif($idiomaUsuario=='de'){ 
header( 'Location: http://de.apartamentosembrujodeazahar.es' ); 
}
else { 
header( 'Location: http://en.apartamentosembrujodeazahar.es' ); 
} 
?>
```

Creo que está bien comentado, pero aún así os dejo alguna aclaración.

La función traeLenguaje es la que es llamada y devuelve los dos primeros dígitos de la variable HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE que es en si misma la que devuelve el idioma del navegador utilizado por el usuario, esta variable luego la guardamos en idiomaUsuario y a continuación simplemente redireccionamos según este. El último condicional es abierto, por si no es ni español ni alemán, que directamente entre en inglés que entendemos es más utilizado.